# Using !important tags with > *

Tags: css, parent-child

I'm currently updating a CMS to make it fully responsive. This obviously involves changing a lot of existing code. However, to make life easier, I was hoping to use examples like this:

```
parent > * {
   element!important;
}
```

In the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/McMEk/2/, I am trying to make all the footer text centred where elements have previously been set to align left (the way I am using this in the site is for where the site is in mobile mode using media queries). I would have thought that making it !important would ensure that this was the case, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong here and how I could make it work without using messy code? Thanks.

Comment: isn't using !important messy in the first place?

Comment: In your fiddle, only the div is matching the selector, as it is the only child. the `p` tag would not be matched because of the child combinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
footer * {
    text-align:center!important;
}
```

Since `>` matched the direct child of your `footer` which is `div` in this case.

Comment: wow. what a morning, just not with it. that's worked perfectly, cheers